# Creating an array of a class with arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to instantiate an array of a class where the constructor takes two arguments, and initialize it in the same line.

Conceptually, I want to do something like this:

```
foo::foo (int A, int B = 10)
{
    V1 = A;
    V2 = B;
}

foo Myfoo[3] = { (1, 100), (2, 300), (5, 100) };
// what I _don't_ want to do is create individual objects like this:
// foo Myfoo1(1, 100); 
// foo Myfoo2(2, 300);
// foo Myfoo3(5, 100);
```

What I found is that when the constructor is called the arguments are not as expected.  The B argument always shows up as the default value of 10.  Just in tinkering I threw in additional arguments in the array initialization.

```
foo Myfoo[3] = { (0, 1, 100), (2, 300, 0), (0, 5, 100, 0) };
```

To my surprise it compiled without error, but I didn't pursue this too far, because it didn't make sense to me - but I was able to affect the problem

Does anyone have an idea on how I *should* code this?  I've already worked around the problem but I'm curious how it should be done properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem [has already been explaind by @songhuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56862529/434551).

I can think of the following ways to resolve the problem.

#### Option 1

Use `{}` instead of `()` to construct objects.

```
foo Myfoo[3] = { {1, 100}, {2, 300}, {5, 100}};
```

#### Option 2

Use `foo` explitly with `()` to construct objects.

```
foo Myfoo[3] = { foo(1, 100), foo(2, 300), foo(5, 100) };
```

#### Option 3

Use `foo` explitly with `{}` to construct objects.

```
foo Myfoo[3] = { foo{1, 100}, foo{2, 300}, foo{5, 100}};
```

Comment: your option 2 worked for me! but doesn't that create an additional foo each time?  I'm wondering if this is one of those cases where you really need to have a copy constructor defined (but I'm not sure I used the right terminology)

Comment: @ElRonaldo, In theory, there is a copy no matter which option you choose. I am not sure whether a compiler is able to elide any of those copy operations.

Answer (score 3):

With the usage of `(1, 100)`, you're just passing one `int` with value `100` to the constructor of `foo`. The [comma-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) just discards the 1st operand, and returns the 2nd operand here. (It doesn't work in the way as you expected like `foo Myfoo1(1, 100);` or `foo(1, 100);`.)

You should use `{}` ( [list initialization (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) ) instead of `()`, i.e.

```
foo Myfoo[3] = { {1, 100}, {2, 300}, {5, 100} };
```

Comment: I tried this using MS Visual Studio 2010 and it will not compile, giving the error message:
1>d:\dev\arraytest\arraytest\arraytest.cpp(24): error C2552: 'Myfoo' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
1>          'foo' : Types with user defined constructors are not aggregate

Comment: @ElRonaldo Does your compiler support C++11? Or it might have some trouble with list initialization. I trid a live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yf80DtFHBk5Bvlnt).

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `{}` instead of `()` and code is working as expected

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
            Test(int a, int b = 10)
            {
                    x = a;
                    y = b;
                    cout << "C-tor" << endl;
            }
            void show()
            {
                    cout << " x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl;
            }
    private:
            int x;
            int y;
};


int main()
{

    Test obj[3] = {{10,20},{30,40}, {50,60}};
    obj[0].show();
    obj[1].show();
    obj[2].show();
    return 0;
 }
```

Above code produces expected output:

> C-tor
>
> C-tor
>
> C-tor
>
> x = 10 y = 20
>
> x = 30 y = 40
>
> x = 50 y = 60

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sinha!  
I copied your example into Visual Studio 2010 and it would not compile  - getting the same error message as songyuanyao's.  
What compiler did you use?

Comment: Thanks @ElRonaldo I'm using g++ on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) On this version I compile the code.